# Where can I get react templates similar to bootstrap templates?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am a beginner in web development and have learnt the basics of react. Where can I get react templates in component form for me to make modification to content and maybe add a few more components? I have tried to download bootstrap templates and convert it into react components but it was too much for me. Also, sites like material ui only seem to provide individual component codes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reactstrap. you can download it via node